# Question About Order of Execution of Functions in React

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, why is the sleep function executed before the startClock function?

```
handleClick = () => {

        this.startClock();
        this.sleep(5000);
}

startClock = () => {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = this.checkTime(m);
        s = this.checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
        var t = setTimeout(function(){this.startClock()}.bind(this), 1000);
      };

checkTime = (i) => {
        if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
        }
           return i;
        };

sleep = (timeout) => {
        var begin = new Date();
        while (new Date() - begin < timeout) {
        }
      };
```

I would expect the startClock function to execute first but the sleep function executes first and then the startClock function.

Comment: Executes, or _completes_?

Comment: These are just function declaration, and from what we can see they never execute.

Comment: @nubinub - the handleClick function is executed when a user clicks a button. I didn't show that for simplicity.

Comment: @isherwood - the startClock function starts a clock that is displayed in a <div>. I would expect that to start after the handleClick function is called. But the sleep function executes first and completes and then the startClock function executes.

Comment: How do you know sleep is executed before startClock ?

Comment: @nubinub - on the screen, the clock starts displaying the time after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I think what is actually happening here is the startClock function is executed first but since the time specified in setTimeout is 1000ms, the sleep function starts before the GUI is updated and therefore the GUI is not updated until sleep is finished.